# Passing arguments to angularjs custom filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `global filter` that filters data based on a text input.

```
<search-box ng-model="vm.filter.keyword"></search-box>
```

And, we use the filter like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="group in vm.groups | searchGlobal:vm.filter.keyword
```

My filter looks like:

```
.filter('searchGlobal',
    function searchGlobal () {
        return function searchGlobal (searchValArr,filterText) {
            var filteredData = [];
            for(var i = 0; i <searchValArr.length; i++) {
                if (searchValArr[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
                searchValArr[i].id.indexOf(filterText) !== -1) {
                    filteredData.push(searchValArr[i]);
                }                        
            }
            return filteredData;
        };
    });
```

Now, this is the problem.

**The fields to look for might just not be** `name` and `id`.

**In some cases they might be** `name`, `phone_numbers`,

**in some case** `name`,`age`,`refNumbers`.

How do I handle the scenario logic inside the filter accordingly?

Comment: Do you pass second param to view `searchGlobal:vm.filter.keyword`? I saw it just one param.

Comment: @TanDuong First param is always the dataset of ngRepeat and the second one is vm.filter.keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more param for checking the property you want

`<tr ng-repeat="group in vm.groups | searchGlobal:vm.filter.keyword:vm.filter.listKeys`

```
.filter('searchGlobal',
function searchGlobal () {
    return function searchGlobal (searchValArr,filterText, listKeys) {
        var filteredData = [];
        var listIdAdd = [];

        if (angular.isUnDefined(listKeys) || !angular.isArray(listKeys)) {
            listKeys = ['name', 'id'];
        }
        for(var i = 0; i <searchValArr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < listKeys.length; j++) {
                if (searchValArr[i][listKeys[j]].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) !== -1 &&
                    listIdAdd.indexOf(searchValArr[i].id === -1)) {
                    filteredData.push(searchValArr[i]);
                    listIdAdd.push(searchValArr[i].id);
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredData;
    };
});
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that will check if any of the object keys contains the keyword.

I have created a simple example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ls5DdmFr4589rcYTuAQ6?p=preview).

The filter function looks like the following, note that it uses some modern JS features like `Object.values` and `String.includes` which can be exchanged if older browser support is required.

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .filter("searchGlobal", function(){
    return function(data, keyword){
      // Return a filtered array of items in the initial array
      return data.filter(function(obj){
        // Check if any (some) of the object keys contains the keyword
        return Object.values(obj).some(function(value){
          return value.includes(keyword);
        });
      });
    };
  });
```